# How to solve this exercise using mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

let $a\in\mathbb{R}^*_{+}$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^1([0,a])$ such that $f(a)f'(a)<0\,\text{and}\,f(0)=0$

Prove that there exists $c\in]0,a[,\, f'(c)=0$

I can suppose that $f(a)>0$ and $f'(a)<0$,then by definition of f'(a)
there exists $x_0\in]0,a[;x_0<x<a\Rightarrow  f(a)<f(x)$

how to continue please

Comment: By the mean value theorem (applied to $[0,a]$ there is a point $x_1: f'(x_1)=\frac{f(0)-f(a)}{0-a}>0$. Since $f'$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem applied to $[x_1,a]$ gives us the existence of a $0$. However, it may be interesting to notice that the conclusion holds even if the function is only supposed to be derivable, thanks to Darboux theorem

Comment: Note that general case also follows as @Caffeine points out. $f'(x_1) = \dfrac{f(a)}{a}$ implies $f'(x_1)$ and $f(a)$ have the same sign. On the other hand you are given $f'(a)$ has the opposite sign with $f(a)$. As a result, $f'(x_1)$ and $f'(a)$ have different sign.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there is no $c\in [0,a]$ s.t. $f'(c) =0$.

By assumption, $f'(a) < 0$. so if there isn't $c$ s.t. $f'(c)=0$ this means that $f'(x) <0$ for all $x\in [0,a]$ (since $f'$ satisfy MVT).

But then $f(0)=0 , f(a) >0$ and $f$ is decreasing from $0$ to $a$ , which is impossible since $f(a)>0$, a contradiction.

So we have $c\in [0,a]$ s.t. $f'(c) = 0$ , as required.

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is supposed to be continuously differentiable, positive at $a$ and locally decreasing around $a$ as $f^\prime(a) <0$, $f$ attains its maximum at $c \in (0,a)$. At that point $f^\prime(c)=0$.

Comment: but in the exercise we must use mean value theorem

Answer (score 0):

From there, choose any $x_1 \in (x_0, a)$. Note that $f(0) = 0 < f(a) < f(x_1)$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists somse point $x_2 \in (0, x_1)$ such that $f(x_2) = f(a)$. Then, apply the MVT to the interval $[x_2, a]$ to obtain a stationary point.